# Change a JS function within WP Plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Wondering how I can insert / change a JS function in a plugin in functions.php instead of modifying the plugin directly?
This plugin is called max mega menu

I have read up about using `add_action` and `remove_action` and custom hooks. I cannot seem to find a good example to work with.

I want to wrap the inner content of the function with this

```
if (!plugin.isMobileView()) {
   //code here
}
```

**UPDATE**

See my answer below - I did not need the plugin script altogether, so I dequeued it.
My question should really be now "**How to disable a wordpress plugin script**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised I did not need the whole plugin script and website was fine without it.

So I dequeued the script

```
function mmm_dequeue_script() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'megamenu' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'mmm_dequeue_script', 100 );
```

Sorry unrelated to the question now.
Cheers hope this help someone trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can enqueue your custom script by checking `mobile device` -

**Example :** In `function.php` file

```
function my_custom_enqueue_script() {
  if (wp_is_mobile()) { #If it is mobile devices
     wp_enqueue_script('my-js','for-mobile-devices.js',false);   #Load your mobile device scripts
  }else{
     wp_enqueue_script('my-js','for-others-devices.js', false ); #Load your other device scripts
  }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_enqueue_script' );
```

Here is the documentations for [wp_is_mobile()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile) and [wp_enqueue_scripts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) function reference

> **Note :** Using above functions, You can separately load your custom script for mobile devices.

Comment: Thanks I will try this!

Answer (score 0):

Please read WP Plugin API official guide **FIRSTLY**(https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API).

The plugin core —— how to add hooks?
Two WP internal functions:

```
add_action ($hookname, $callbackfunction)
add_filter ($hookname,$callbackfunction)
```

if u dont understand , u can see the WP official plugin —— Hello Dolly!